# finding either A or B class within a loop, then executing similar code

Tags: jquery

I'm following a tutorial to learn jQuery in 30 days over at Tuts+. I have recently completed day #7, which goes over how to appendTo, prependTo, and such.

The lesson ended with a "useable scenario" where a span is wrapped around specific text in a blog post, and that wrapped text is then taken, and prepended to the paragraph, and floated to the side to make a pretty quote example.

Here is what I have so far at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wc6ny2xn/)

I've taken it and modified it a little, to also do a "pull the quote to the left" function.

What my question is, how could create a wrapping loop that could search for either "qo_right" or "qo_left" instead of having two duplicate functions.

```
(function() {

var qo_right = $('article').find('span.qo_right').each(function (){
  var $this = $(this);

  $('<blockquote></blockquote>', {
    class: 'qo_right',
    text: $this.text()
  }).prependTo( $this.closest('p') );
});

var qo_left = $('article').find('span.qo_left').each(function (){
  var $this = $(this);

  $('<blockquote></blockquote>', {
    class: 'qo_left',
    text: $this.text()
  }).prependTo( $this.closest('p') );
});
})();
```

There's so many different ways I could think of doing this, or writing it, but I'm running into a lot of confusion and errors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, target both of them in one selector:

```
$('span.qo_left, span.qo_right')
```

Then in your iteration, you could set the class depending on which class the current element has:

```
'class': $(this).hasClass('qo_left') ? 'qo_left' : 'qo_right'
```

Of course if you know that `qo_left` and `qo_right`, respectively, are the *only* classes on the span, you could copy the class attribute entirely:

```
'class': $(this).attr('class')
```

Note that I've quoted "class" in the assignment, which will give you better browser compatibility, since "class" is a reserved keyword in JavaScript.

Comment: David, thanks for the response. I'm not familiar with the '?' mark in the middle of the second line of code. Could you tell me what this is called so I can go find some reference material? Still pretty new to all of this. Thanks man!

Comment: It's called a *ternary operator* if you want to google it. It's shorthand for if/then/else. Syntax is `condition ? case-true : case-false`. `var x = y>3 ? 1 : 2` is equal to `if(y > 3) { x = 1; } else { x = 2; }`

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a function that takes as a parameter qo_direction?

```
function pullQuote(qo_direction) {
    var qo = $('article').find('span.' + qo_direction).each(function (){
        var $this = $(this);

        $('<blockquote></blockquote>', {
            class: qo_direction,
            text: $this.text()
        }).prependTo( $this.closest('p') );
    });
    return qo;
}
```

And you use it this way:

```
var qo_right = pullQuote("qo_right");
var qo_left = pullQuote("qo_left");
```